# Jest es6 class mock returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have a simple class that I want to mock and for some reason jest returns undefined.

Here's the code:

```
import { MyClass as myClass } from './my-class'; 
jest.mock('./my-class', () => jest.fn());
console.log(myClass); // undefined
```

When I log myClass I get `undefined`.

If I mock without mocking the implementation, I get this:

```
import { MyClass as myClass } from './my-class'; 
jest.mock('./my-class');
console.log(myClass);
```

The code above logs:
`function MyClass() {return mockConstructor.apply(this,arguments);}`

Which does not allow for mocking, since it is not a `jest.fn()` and it has none of the useful methods like `mockImplementation`.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Did you try the way described here - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mock the `my-class` module correctly. You are using `Named Exports`, you also need to mock this.

E.g.

`my-class.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {}
```

`my-class.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass as myClass } from './my-class';
jest.mock('./my-class', () => ({ MyClass: jest.fn() }));
console.log(myClass);
```

Output:

```sh
  console.log
    { [Function: mockConstructor]
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function],
      mockReset: [Function],
      mockRestore: [Function],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
      mockReturnValue: [Function],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
      mockImplementation: [Function],
      mockReturnThis: [Function],
      mockName: [Function],
      getMockName: [Function] }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Now I don't see `undefined` but I get the following:
`function () { return fn.apply(this, arguments);}`

Comment: Actually, even if I don't use names exports, I get the same effect.

Comment: @yccteam Can't reproduce it. Here is the source code of anwser: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61586904

Comment: The strangest thing - the mock works. It just throws an error when I'm trying to use `mockRestore` or `mockImplementation`:
https://gist.github.com/YonatanKra/15725ff347afb17c50c65aca27fd5f4e

Comment: Can you provide the code about how do you use `mockImplementation` and `mockRestore `?

Comment: It is in the gist I've sent above: https://gist.github.com/YonatanKra/15725ff347afb17c50c65aca27fd5f4e